# Front Matter Data in Layouts is not working Eleventy

Tags: javascript, nunjucks, eleventy, jamstack

I'm having troubles using front matter in my layouts. It simply displays out the front matter to the page without creating the data needed for my layout.

Here goes the code:

*/src/_includes/layouts/base.html*

```html
---
rightLinks : [
        {
            "icon": "mail_outline",
            "href": "https://google.com"
        }
    ]
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-AR">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/global.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- top-nav try to use rightLinks data from this layout -->
  {% include "partials/top-nav.html" %}
  {% include "partials/main-nav.html" %}
  <main tabindex="-1" id="main-content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</main>
</body>
</html>
```

---

*/src/_includes/layouts/home.html*

```html
{% extends "layouts/base.html" %} 
{% block content %}

<section class="hero is-black is-fullheight-with-navbar hero-home">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h1 class="title text-black text-huge">
          Nexus Materiales Eléctricos
        </h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle is-4">
          Somos mayoristas en insúmos eléctricos de calidad.
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-6">
        <a href="/marcas" class="button is-rounded is-large is-dark is-uppercase text-semi-black">
          ver marcas
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section has-background-white">
  <h2 class="title">Nuestras marcas destacadas</h2>
  <h3 class="subtitle">Calidad y seguridad</h3>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

---

*/src/index.md*

```
---
title: 'Hello World!'
layout: 'layouts/home'
---
```

I get as a visual result the actual string at the top:
[image]

It seems to me that Eleventy, for some reason, is skipping the front matter.

*Here is my Eleventy configuration file:*

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.addWatchTarget("./src/sass/");
    config.addPassthroughCopy('./src/images')

    // Return your Object options:
    return {
        dir: {
            input: "src",
            output: "dist"
        },
        markdownTemplateEngine: 'njk',
        dataTemplateEngine: 'njk',
        htmlTemplateEngine: 'njk',
    }
  };
```

Someone can explain to me why is this happening, and how can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Not an issue I think, but Eleventy looks in _includes for layouts. Your file is _includes/layouts/base.html. When you specify the layout in your template, are you doing something like: layouts/base ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this myself. Maybe share your template calling it?

Comment: Hello Raymond, I've just updated this question with the new code. As you'll notice, I'm defining data in a 'base' layout. That *data* will be used by a partial called 'top-nav'. By the moment, I've moved this information to _data where I can access this information at global, but this is not ideal. I really wanted to be as a front matter in my base.html layout.

Comment: I think front matter is parsed by Eleventy, not Nunjucks, which is why you are seeing it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front-matter data is only available in layout files that are directly referenced by pages with the `layout:` front matter key, **not** with Nunjucks `{% extends %}`. Front matter data in directly referenced layout files are merged with other data as part of [11ty's data cascade](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-cascade/). ([11ty docs: front matter in layouts](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/layouts/#front-matter-data-in-layouts))

For example:

```markdown
<!-- index.md -->
---
layout: layouts/content
---
# some content here
```

```
{# layouts/base.njk #}
---
hello: "world"
---
{# ^ the above will be printed as plain text and isn't available #}
```

```
{# layouts/content.njk #}
---
someKey: "something"
---
{% extends "layouts/base.njk" %}

{{ someKey }}
{# ^ this will render "something" as expected #}
```

This is likely because `{% extends %}` is a feature of Nunjucks, and Eleventy is not aware of which other Nunjucks files are being referenced.

For your situation, you have a couple of options. First, you could place your front matter data in `layouts/home`, since that's what you're referencing in your `index.md`. Another option is to just use [Nunjuck's `set` tag](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#set).

```
{% set links = [
    {
        "icon": "mail_outline",
        "href": "https://google.com"
    }
] %}

{% for link in links %}
    {{ link.icon }}
    {{ link.href }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your answer is really nice and helped me a lot. In this case, I'll use `set` inside a partial for rendering those links. Thank you.

Comment: So that means I need to add nunjucks as a dependency?